# add properties file to jar

Tags: java, jar, properties-file

I have a properties file config.properties that I am accessing in a java project in Eclipse.

```
 BufferedReader  bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("config.properties")));
```

This works fine when I run the project in Eclipse.  But when I export the project as a jar file, config.properties is not included in the jar and when I run the jar I get the following error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties

How can I package my property file so it is included and used in my jar?

Comment: Gotta add that bad boy to your resources.

Comment: If you are storing your configuration inside `config.properties` file then why do you want to include this (properties) file inside jar ? Normally we use properties file to store some data which can be modified easily  as required. If you include configuration file inside `jar` then what is the use of properties file. You can store inside java class like making `Constant.java`

Comment: Also consider to use the Properties class to load properties files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exporting your JAR, in the "Select the resources to export" panel, you need to put a checkmark next to "config.properties".

Then, you'll need to change the way you load the properties file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")));
```

Also properties files usually aren't read that way -- try Properties.load:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(PropsSaver.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
```